# Определить в любой момент времени, нажата ли клавиша

Tags: qt

Пишу кроссплатформенное приложение на Qt. Аналога функции `GetAsyncKeyState` в Qt я не нашёл, поэтому завёл массив состояний клавиш нажата\отпущена и стал заполнять его, обрабатывая события окна `keyPressEvent` и `keyReleaseEvent`. Но оказалось, что буквенные коды зависят от раскладки, а цифры зависят от нажатой кнопки Shift. Как узнать, нажата ли кнопка W, независимо от того, какая раскладка (русская, английская, японская и т.д.) выбрана? Пробовал `nativeScanCode()`, но он возвращает какие-то странные значения, которые нужно самому переводить в буквы. Я бы перевёл, но будут ли эти значения одинаковы для всех клавиатур и всех платформ?

И ещё. Если событие `keyReleaseEvent` будет потеряно, например, при переключении фокуса в другое окно, то клавиша будет считаться нажатой. Как решить эту проблему?

В Xlib у меня была такая же проблема, но она решается таким трюком

```
key=XkbKeycodeToKeysym(display, XKeysymToKeycode(display, key), 0, 1);
```

Есть ли что-то подобное, но платформонезависимое в Qt? И кстати, это нормальный трюк или хак? А то когда я создаю окно через XLib, то у меня иногда программа внезапно завершается. То ли сегфолт, то ли клавиша распознаётся как Esc. Пока не поймал этот баг. Может быть из-за этого трюка?

Comment: не [это](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/587-Query-keyboard-state-in-Qt-3) ?

Comment: Нет. Там же Control, а модификаторы меня не интересуют.